# Inserting rows in workbook using win32com in python not working

Tags: python, win32com

I have a very specific question. The line:

```
expform_ws.Range("Total").Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

in the code below is not working:

```
# Write data in expenses form
expform_wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(expform_path, Editable=True)
expform_ws = expform_wb.Worksheets('Expense Form')
last_row_ef = expense_items + 15

expform_ws.Range("Total").Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
expform_ws.Range('Casecode').Value = case_code
expform_ws.Range('D6').Value = name
expform_ws.Range('D7').Value = last_name
expform_ws.Range('D8').Value = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
expform_ws.Range('B16:B' + str(last_row_ef)).Value = date
expform_ws.Range('D16:D' + str(last_row_ef)).Value = descr
```

In case this helps: the line gets highlighted in PyCharm as "Statement seems to have no effect".

Anyone can help to spot what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `expform_ws.Range("Total").Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert` this indeed doesnt do anything, im no familiar with win32com specifically, but i think you are missing the `()` at the end of that line to actually call the function

Comment: @Nullman, you are right! I was missing that. Now it works. How stupid...

Comment: very common oversight, don't worry about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
expform_ws.Range("Total").Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

You aren't actually CALLING the function, you are just getting "reference" to it, add () to call it

```
expform_ws.Range("Total").Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert()
```